# Update Plugin's config.php

Tags: plugin-development, control-panel, php, configuration

Is it possible to update the config.php file in a plugin outside of manually opening and adjusting the array? I'm hoping there's a way I can have a certain user group be able to change the array values with the plugin's control panel page.

The config file is very simple, it looks like this:

```
<?php 

return [

    'active_features' => [
         'change_team' => false,
         'change_series' => false,
         'change_user_settings' => false,
    ],

];
```

And I need a way for them to be able to toggle, say, 'change_team' to true or false every so often. I've searched around and haven't found anything at all to try. Does this kind of functionality exist at all?

Comment: Wouldn't you just want to use the Plugin settings for this? The settings have a UI and save to the db, which does exactly what you want. The config files are meant to only be updated manually updating them. I could be wrong, but if it were me I would just create a settings page for this.

Comment: I'll look into plugin settings, I didn't even know about those. So much to learn with Craft!

Comment: @JustinKimbrell Wanna add that as an answer, Justin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation you don't want to use a config file and instead you want to use plugin settings. The settings have a UI and save to the db, which does exactly what you want. The config files are meant to only be updated manually updating them.

http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/plugin-settings